# PTAM Configuration Files

Tags: ros, ethzasl-ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed on my ROS Indigo System ptam.

I want to use the camera calibration. But in the [Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/Tutorials/camera_calibration) on Step 4 it says :

Edit the PtamFixParams.yaml file and set the parameters "ImageSizeX" "ImageSizeY" to your image resolution.

Edit the cameracalibrator.launch file to map the image to your image topic. Point the camera to the calibration pattern and only then start the cameracalibrator node.

My Question is where is the PtamFixParams.yaml and cameracalibrator.launch file to map in the ptam sources to edit the configuration to the right camera input?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208177/ptam-configuration-files/) by [Nepitwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22291/nepitwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is located in ethzasl_ptam/ptam/

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2015-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nepitwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22291/nepitwin/) on 2015-05-04**:
It works now after i configured my Node :-) Thanks